# Post upload clipboard paste for Markdown syntax, for uploaded files - in Fine Uploader

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I just found Fine Uploader today, after having searched for a javascript uploader that will also support posting the file to Amazon S3. I read the documents as much as I could and searched this site, but I don't think there's anything about this specifically.

As a user of wikis and Markdown (it's ubiquitous, here, on github, in our internal ERP database and so on), I'd like to be able to easy copy-paste a "syntax complete" string, after a file is uploaded, because that would really make documentation creation easier.

The workflow I envision -

- make screenshots locally
- drag the screenshots or other files to the Fine Uploader upload area on a page
- files in the session are uploaded and presented in the result list with a button at its top, allowing the user to copy the markdown syntax for the one or more files, to the clipboard.

Then I can paste the result into whatever textarea I want. Something like:

```
![This is image 1](http://mys3_url.tdl/path/to/this_is_image_1.png)
![This is image 2](http://mys3_url.tdl/path/to/this_is_image_2.png)
[Link to a PDF](http://mys3_url.tdl/path/to/this_is_my_pdf_1.pdf))
```

For bonus points, I'd like to add an icon to represent the non-image file type, to its left.   Something like:

```
![](http://url.tdl/path/to/icon.png)[Link to a PDF](http://mys3_url.tdl/path/to/this_is_my_pdf_1.pdf))
```

I imagine there's a way to do this, with a cursory look at the Events and API methods. But would you be so kind as to point me at events or API methods of interest?

Please advise. If this is the wrong place for this and if it needs to be posted at your github, I will do so. Let me know, please.

Thank you for your assistance in advance.
Kind regards
Rick

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding your specific question here.  Where is this markdown coming from, and what is its purpose?  The last step in your workflow is a bit confusing.  I'm not really sure what you're trying to do with Fine Uploader, other than upload files.  

If you're looking to account for a portion of your workflow that occurs after the files are uploaded, then Fine Uploader's job is already done.  Please advise with a bit more detail in the context of Fine Uploader.

Comment: Hi @RayNicholus - after Fine Uploader is done uploading, I'd like to make a button appear on the result page, that when clicked, grabs all the resulting URLs, formats them in Markdown syntax, and pastes to the clipboard. Then, I would switch to a system that accepts Markdown, and paste all the Markdown-formatted URLs I have on the clipboard.

Comment: (Can't seem to make a newline in here, sorry). I'd like to ask what API structure, method or event could be used to accomplish this, if any exists. Does the resulting grid of files, for instance, exist in an array that I can use.

Comment: The workflow I'm thinking of is making documentation. Fine Uploader seems like an excellent and easy way to get files uploaded to an S3 bucket, and I just want to try to take away the tedium of having to open every uploaded file to get the URL, for each in a group of say 20 screenshots, and then format it in Markdown.

Comment: And by the way, @RayNicholus, thanks for responding.

Comment: To answer your questions specifically, though, @RayNicholus, a) the markdown-formatted URLs are coming from some custom script my team would write, and b) the purpose of the markdown-formatted URLs is to make the whole process of uploading files and making markdown-formatted URLs for pasting, simple and quick. The goal is the alleviate any pain in a documentation process where people are uploading a bunch of screenshots into some document or procedure.

Comment: Got it.  Fine Uploader's involvement here is minimal.  I'll write up a short answer explaining next chance I get.

Comment: Thanks very much in advance, @RayNicholus. Appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are simply looking for a way to easily retrieve the url in S3 of each uploaded file.  This can be done by having your server return the URL of the file in the response to the [upload success POST request sent by Fine Uploader](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/endpoint_handlers/amazon-s3.html#optional-server-side-tasks-all-browsers).  Fine Uploader will return the response (assumed to be JSON) to your [`onComplete` event handler](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#complete).

For example, say your server returns the following response to an upload success POST: `{"url": "http://mys3_url.tdl/path/to/this_is_image_1.png"}`.  You can access this response in your `onComplete` event handler like this:

```
var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
    ...
    callbacks: {
        onComplete: function(id, name, responseJSON) {
            var urlOfFile = responseJSON.url;
            ...
        }
    }

});
```

At this point, you can so whatever you please with these URLs.

Comment: Much appreciated, @RayNicholus! That points me in the right direction within what you've developed. I'm sorry I cannot upvote you, but I have no "reputation" on here, so...